# Download (update) file from URL in Android. File's name is changing

Tags: java, android, http, url

Okay, so I can download file from serwer WWW (my server)

```
    private void OnlyDownFile() {
        nameFiles = "test.xlsx";
        final String allUrlString = "http://xx.xxx.x.xxx/test/" + nameFiles;
        DownloadManager downloadManager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri Download_Uri = Uri.parse(allUrlString);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Download_Uri);

        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
        request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
        request.setTitle("My Data Download");
        request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");
        request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(this, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, nameFiles);
}
```

And this is okay and works well (I download from my server)

I have a `PROBLEM` with update file. I want to check: Do you have newer file (at Serwer)? Yes - download newer. No - use the last which you download. 
And situation where you don't have Internet - use the last which you download, otherwise TOAST "Turn on Internet"(Toast is no problem :) ).

I don't have any idea How check newer file ? and problem with other names?

Comment: The subject of your post is not found in the body of it. So what is the problem when you say `And this is okay and works well `?

Comment: @greenapps You're right!

Comment: Then why don't  you edit your subject and or post?